# SignalR performs long polling instead of websocket in case of cross domain

Tags: websocket, cross-domain, signalr

When I connect to signalR hosted in same virtual directory, I get data via websocket transport.  But in case of cross domain, long polling is getting used as a transport.

Here browser compatibility is not an issue as I am trying in Chrome browser.

What I can do to use websocket as a transport in case of cross domain.

I have tried every possible solution available on net, including available at signalR wiki.

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client-Hubs

Comment: Are you using the same server from another domain?

Comment: Using IIS 6.0, .Net 4.0.  Earlier I wrongly mentioned that **"When I connect to signalR hosted in same virtual directory, I get data via websocket transport"**.  Actually it uses Server side event in case of chrome ff when in same Vir Dir.  Does SignalR having support for SSE in case of cross domain for Chrome,FF? -Thanks.

Comment: Because only IIS8 supports websockets and neither SSE or ForeverFrame works cross domain so you're stuck with long polling

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks David for answering my question in the comments:

> Because only IIS8 supports websockets and neither SSE or ForeverFrame works cross domain so you're stuck with long polling –